# Taskbar icons no longer appear in Windows 10 (start menu also broken)

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

My partners laptop has somehow just stopped showing the windows 10 icons in the taskbar nor can she use the Windows start menu button - when clicked it simply does nothing.

Can anyone suggest why this has happened and how to remedy this - there is a screenshot below to illustrate the problem further.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the PC?

Comment: I've seen this happen before, unfortunately I ended up having to do a clean install of Windows. You can create an installation CD/DVD/USB stick using the Media Creation Tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10ISO. Make sure to back up your files first, as this will erase EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

How bizarre... my partner restarted it the next day and it is now fixed...